# How to include a struct in a function's decision making?

Tags: struct, rust

I am trying to learn struct usage and want to create a function that  takes a struct name (citizen3030) and gives some information about that person.

Where I'm tripping up is declaring inbound type `fn get_social_status(<what to put here>)` when the type comes from the struct.  I wish I knew how to describe it better.

Side Note:  This is not real for any actual real project, I'm just trying to learn and had Star Citizen video playing in the background. Also, using static strings was just for experimenting.

```
#[derive(Debug)] 

struct Citizen {
   id_num: u32,
   weight: u32,
   height: u32,
   first_name: &'static str,
   last_name: &'static str,
   phone_number: &'static str,
   age: u32,
   sex: &'static str,
   marital_status: &'static str,
   social_rating: u32
}

// it does not like any of the variables below
impl Citizen {
   fn get_social_status(&self, &String) {
       if Citizen.social_rating >= 7 {println!("Good");}
       if Citizen.social_rating >= 5 && Citizen.age <= 20 {println!("Fair");}
       else {println!("Not Great");}
   }
}

fn main() {
   
   let citizen3030 = Citizen {
       id_num: 1,
       weight: 100,
       height: 55,
       first_name: "Jake",
       last_name: "Doe",
       phone_number: "555-555-3232",
       age: 17,
       sex: "m",
       marital_status: "Married",
       social_rating: 5
   };
   let citizen3031 = Citizen {
       id_num: 2,
       weight: 255,
       height: 78,
       first_name: "Lex",
       last_name: "Luther",
       phone_number: "333-333-2323",
       age: 56,
       sex: "m",
       marital_status: "Single",
       social_rating: 7
   };
   println!("{:?}",citizen3030);
   println!("{:?}",citizen3031);

   println!("First Name of cit3030, {}", citizen3030.first_name );

   let temps = citizen3031.first_name;
   println!("{}", temps);

   get_social_status(citizen3030); 
   
}
```

Comment: Put them in a `HashMap<String, Citizen>`?

Comment: Is [this code](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=45512f7cfc8e4108b7f27ee64b71bc56) what you're looking for? The `self` parameter is the object being called.

Comment: That's it!  Ah!  Thank you so much.  My first post and it was answered right away.  Amazing.  Again, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Methods take in `self` (or variants like `&self` or `&mut self`) and refer to the value being called. So you can implement your function simply as:

```
impl Citizen {
    fn get_social_status(&self) {
        if self.social_rating >= 7 {
            println!("Good");
        } else if self.social_rating >= 5 && self.age <= 20 {
            println!("Fair");
        } else {
            println!("Not Great");
        }
    }
}
```

and call it using:

```
citizen3030.get_social_status();
```

Perhaps you can read through [Method Syntax from the Rust Programming Language Book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch05-03-method-syntax.html).